# How to use the value of a global variable?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I have declared two variables globally in  my js code. In one of the function I am storing the value of the screen coordinates in them. Now I want to use these values in another function. How can I do that?

```
var xCoord;
var yCoord;

var getBrowserCood = $("#Boma").mousedown(function(e) {
    if(e.button==2){
        xCoord = e.pageX;
        yCoord = e.pageY;
    }
});
```

Comment: Just use them? But make sure the event handler did actually run before you call the other function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have declared `xCoord` and `yCoord` globally, **they will be already be available to other functions**:

```
var xCoord;
var yCoord;

var getBrowserCood = $("#Boma").mousedown(function(e) {
    if(e.button==2){
        xCoord = e.pageX;
        yCoord = e.pageY;
    }
});

function anotherFunction() {
    console.log(xCoord);
    console.log(yCoord);
}

anotherFunction();
```

If you want to keep these variables global, it may be more clear to refer to them using the `window` object like this:

```
window.xCoord
window.yCoord
```

Some related topics which you may want to look into are [scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) and [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1).